# How adding an item in the ArrayList and ArrayAdpter

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm doing a chat and I need to increment a list with the messages sent though I am unable to do.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_janela);
    ArrayList<String> mensagens = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mensagens);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This method below I get the message text and is where I wanted to increase the list.

```
private void escreve(String texto) {
    mensagens.add(texto);
}
```

I hope it has become clear , thanks for attention

Comment: What's the error? How does it not work?

Comment: you're missing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 2):

Declare both arralist and adapter outside and then just notify when data changed so it will work, check below solution.

```
  ArrayList<String> mensagens;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_janela);
     mensagens = new ArrayList<String>();
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mensagens);
     ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}


 private void escreve(String texto) {
      mensagens.add(texto);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error: You cannot create a list as local variable in one method and use it in another. You have to make `mensages` a class variable.

Comment: okay so I should acriar ArrayList < String> messages before the onCreate method of android and using it in the method that I wish increments ? even instantiating it in onCreate ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a member variable.

And you can add to an ArrayAdapter directly without needing to notifyDatasetChanged

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_janela);
    ArrayList<String> mensagens = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mensagens);
    ... 

private void escreve(String texto) {
    adapter.add(texto);
}
```